# Multiple SlideToggle on one page, how to control each on independently

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I'm setting up a few jquery slideToggle for a filter system I have and I'm trying to have them use the same classes. There will be about 5 of the same slide toggle on the page but when I close / open one of them, it closes them all and I'm wondering how I can adjust the the javascript so each one closes individually.

```
<div class="tc-facet-header tc-toggle-show">
        <h3>Header One</h3>
        <span><i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i><i class="bi bi-chevron-up"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="tc-facet tc-facet-open">
        Fitler Content 1
    </div>

<div class="tc-facet-header tc-toggle-show">
        <h3>Header two</h3>
        <span><i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i><i class="bi bi-chevron-up"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="tc-facet tc-facet-open">
        Fitler Content 2
    </div>
```

The JS I use is

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var $content = $(".tc-facet").show();
    $(".tc-facet-header").on("click", function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass("tc-toggle-show");
        $(this).toggleClass("tc-toggle-hide");
        $content.slideToggle();
    });
    });
```

When I click on a h3 header of either one it will open / close both the .tc-facet divs instead of just the one i click on.

Answer (score 0):

Your current jquery code is targeting all `.tc-facet` that's why. You need to target each individual `.tc-facet`. Try this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tc-facet-header").on("click", function(e){
        $(this).toggleClass("tc-toggle-show");
        $(this).toggleClass("tc-toggle-hide");
        $(this).next(".tc-facet").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tc-facet-header tc-toggle-show">
    <h3>Header One</h3>
    <span><i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i><i class="bi bi-chevron-up"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="tc-facet tc-facet-open">
    Fitler Content 1
</div>

<div class="tc-facet-header tc-toggle-show">
    <h3>Header two</h3>
    <span><i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i><i class="bi bi-chevron-up"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="tc-facet tc-facet-open">
    Fitler Content 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since I looked at any jquery code, but from what I can see, the reason you're seeing all of them toggle is that you're running the `slideToggle` function on the `$content` variable you set earlier which includes all of the matches at the time the variable is set.

If all you're trying to do is run the `slideToggle` function on the span when the heading is clicked, you can just do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tc-facet-header").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tc-facet-header tc-toggle-show">
  <h3>Header One</h3>
  <span><i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i><i class="bi bi-chevron-up"></i
      ></span>
</div>
<div class="tc-facet tc-facet-open">Fitler Content 1</div>

<div class="tc-facet-header tc-toggle-show">
  <h3>Header two</h3>
  <span><i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i><i class="bi bi-chevron-up"></i
      ></span>
</div>
<div class="tc-facet tc-facet-open">Fitler Content 2</div>
```

As long as the span follows the heading, then the span will always be toggled.